# Can I remove duplicates and keep formulas within the range?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I am using the remove duplicates value to remove duplicate rows, however, the entire row is deleted while I would like to preserve formulas in the middle of the range in which Excel searches for duplicates. Is that possible?

Illustration:

```
1 Identifier1 Formulatopreserve Datablock1
2 Identifier2 Formulatopreserve Datablock2
3 Identifier1 Formulatopreserve Datablock1
```

Currently, Excel will produce the following result:

```
1 Identifier1 Formulatopreserve Datablock1
2 Identifier2 Formulatopreserve Datablock2
3
```

But I would like it to be:

```
1 Identifier1 Formulatopreserve Datablock1
2 Identifier2 Formulatopreserve Datablock2
3             Forumlatopreserve
```

A little bit more background:
I have written a sub where I import a lot of rows of data and then use sumifs formulas to the right of my data table to sum those rows with the same identifier. I transfer the resulting values back to the original data set and delete the side-calculation. Then, I remove duplicates.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub Import()
'Other dim statements    
Dim k As Integer: k = 0
Dim toname As String: toname = ThisWorkbook.Name

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Clear previous inputs
Workbooks(toname).Worksheets("input A").Range("B6:B1000").ClearContents
Workbooks(toname).Worksheets("input A").Range("I6:AO1000").ClearContents

'Importing happens here, data is in column B and column I to AO
'Columns C-H contain forumlas which I would like to keep

'Remove and sum duplicate
Set ws = Workbooks(toname).Worksheets("input A")
lastrw = ws.Cells(1048576, 2).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("AP6:BV" & lastrw).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(SUMIFS(C[-33],C2,RC2),"""")"
ws.Range("I6:AO" & lastrw).Value = ws.Range("AP6:BV" & lastrw).Value
ws.Range("AP6:BV" & lastrw).ClearContents
With ws.Range("B6:AO" & lastrw)
       .RemoveDuplicates Array(1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40), xlNo
End With

'Remove empty rows (empty in B) but content in column I
lastrw2 = ws.Cells(1048576, 9).End(xlUp).Row
For j = 6 To lastrw2
If ws.Cells(j, 2) = "" Then
ws.Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next j

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

My only idea to fix this is to include code at the end of the sub which writes the formulas I want back into the respective cells and then uses autofill to copy them down. But because it is 7 columns, i.e. 14 lines of code, I would rather not do it if there is a way.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

### Assuming that that the formulas start in row 6:

```
Dim fillRange As Range
With Range("B6:AO" & lastrw)
    For Each fillRange In .Columns
        If fillRange.Cells(1, 1).HasFormula Then fillRange.FillDown
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I do not understand how this code removes duplicates? Could you explain a bit more how this works? Thank you very much.

Comment: It doesn't but you code does.  My answer is meant to work with your code.  It will filldown your formulas to the last row